# R: putting composite plotting characters into a legend

Tags: r, plot, legend

I want to plot to data sets on one canvas. To make one dataset stand out from the other I'll plot it twice using two different characters e.g. a circle around a dot.

Now I want to add this composite character into the legend.

How?

Thank you!

PK
^_^

Comment: Tried calling `legend` 2 times - once for each character of composite?

Comment: It works! I had a problem in my code. Thanks!!!